# How to abort gRPC streaming on error and indicate the error in C++

Tags: c++11, error-handling, grpc

I'm sending a synchronous stream of gRPC messages from a client written in C++, in the following sequence:

- Obtain an unique_ptr to a ClientWriter
- Call its Write() method with messages as many times as needed.
- Call its WritesDone() method
- Call Finish() to obtain the server's status.

How would I abort this sequence in case of a client-side error and indicate that to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a client_context.TryCancel() followed by a Finish(). There are some examples in
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/test/cpp/end2end/end2end_test.cc, ClientCancelsRequestStream. I adapted it to look closer to your code.

```
RequestType request;
ResponseType response;
ClientContext context;
request.set_message("hello");

auto client_writer = stub_->YourRPC(&context, &response);
client_writer->Write(request);
client_writer->Write(request);

client_context.TryCancel();

Status s = client_writer->Finish();
```

If your cancellation is successful, s.error_code() == grpc::StatusCode::CANCELLED.

Here is the comment from ClientContext::TryCancel() in client_context.h in the grpc repository:

```
/// Send a best-effort out-of-band cancel on the call associated with
/// this client context.  The call could be in any stage; e.g., if it is
/// already finished, it may still return success.
///
/// There is no guarantee the call will be cancelled.
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide the code around line 1053 in your answer, as it may change someday.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22136678)

Comment: Done and thanks for the feedback. As a frequent user of SO, I definitely appreciate the code inlined.